# Google how can I create a music player for my Google Assistant

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, audio-player

I’m wondering how I can create a music Player for my Google Assistant compatible devices (e.g. Google Home mini, my tablet, phone...). I’ve been researching about how I can do this, but I’ve just found things like using [Dialogflow](https://dialogflow.com), node-js and/or [Actions on Google](https://developers.google.com/actions/) using [Google Firebase Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/). I’m new to all this, I was motivated by Spotify and Pandora and all those other services. So I also tried looking up how they do it, but I found nothing. If any of you Know how to do it, **please** help me.

In addition to all that, I am just a tad bit confused about the whole Dialogflow and Actions on Google integration, but that’s easier to fix than the overall question.

If this isn’t “solvable” is there a way to do it with Dialogflow Fulfillment’s?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to create something like Spotify or Pandora, you need to partner with Google to create a [media action](https://developers.google.com/actions/media/). These are different than the [conversational actions](https://developers.google.com/actions/extending-the-assistant#conversational_actions) that you can create using Actions on Google and Dialogflow.

If you want to create a conversational action with Actions on Google and Dialogflow that produce long-form audio results as part of the conversation, you will want to look into the [Media response](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#media_responses), which you can include in your replies.

Comment: Thank you, Those links were very helpful, I didn’t know that you had to partner with google in order to create a media app like Spotify or Pandora.